# most 301 redirect going to the same wrong page

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I am moving one site to another.  I have set up individual redirects.  But all pages are going to the "home" page instead of the target pages.  Those target pages are valid.  What is going on?

The original base url is https://www.ojolie.com

Here are some examples.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /cards/corporate https://corporate.ojolie.com/home  
RedirectMatch 301 /cards/corporate/contactus https://corporate.ojolie.com/contact_us 
RedirectMatch 301 /cards/corporate/faq https://corporate.ojolie.com/faq  
RedirectMatch 301 /cards/corporate/viewcard/506 https://corporate.ojolie.com/card/peace--joy
RedirectMatch 301 /cards/corporate/viewcard/507 https://corporate.ojolie.com/card/paper-snowflake
```

Comment: RedirectMatch works with regular expressions, and since you did not anchor your patterns at the beginning and end, the pattern `/cards/corporate` of course matches on `/cards/corporate/contactus` etc. as well.

Comment: `^` anchors the pattern to the start of the test string, and `$` anchors it to the end. `RedirectMatch 301 ^/cards/corporate$ https://corporate.ojolie.com/home `

Comment: @CBroe That IS the problem. That fixes it.  Thank you so much!